# Are there any linear congruential generator algorithms that return only positive values?

Tags: algorithm, integer, prng

I am aware of one; the ZX Spectrum [apparently](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MINSTD#Parameters_in_common_use) used a Lehmer RNG with modulus 65537, and multiplier 75. This only generates numbers greater than zero. However, I'd like to use something with a period of more than 2^16 - 1.

I'm using this in a language with a 32-bit word length for integers (Haxe), so ideally it would be smaller than 2^31. However, I'm not necessarily looking for a Haxe-specific answer.

Comment: negative is just interpretation...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand, care to elaborate? I'm looking to return a positive integer from a function. I tried the obvious but using Math.abs() slowed things down considerably.

Comment: Have you seen this page? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator You generate positive values by not including the sign bit in the output.

Comment: Using Math.Abs() slowed things down considerably? That doesn't seem right...  How about `if (result < 0) return -1 * result;`?

Comment: Or you could just AND the result with 0x7FFFFFF. That will clear the high bit of any negative result. That is, `return result & 0x7FFFFFF;`

Comment: Mark: I have read that page extensively, but it didn't occur to me to not include the sign bit, which I believe Jim was suggesting as well.

Comment: Mbeckish: I'm trying to keep the complexity of this operation as low as possible for speed, but that would probably work!

Comment: Jim: That is a really good suggestion! I'm not particularly familiar with bitwise operators, so this solution didn't occur to me. It also has no impact on speed. You should have provided that as an answer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In machines that use twos complement (which means the x86 and derivatives, and pretty much any other computer you're likely to encounter), the high bit is used to indicate sign. If the high bit is set, then the number is negative.

So you can ensure that a number is positive by clearing the high bit. In the case of a 32-bit number, it's a simple matter of:

```
result = result & 0x7FFFFFFF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this should have been obvious, but I figured it out. Here's my equation:

`internalSeed = ( internalSeed * MULTIPLIER + INCREMENT ) % MODULUS + MODULUS;`

To prevent exceeding the word length for an integer, while still providing a large period of returns, I went with the Microsoft Visual Basic 6 pseudorandom values:

```
MULTIPLIER = 1140671485
INCREMENT = 12820163
MODULUS = 16777216
```

Then the `+ MODULUS` value of course changes the range from ( -16777216, 16777216 ) to ( 0, 33554429 ) which is what I wanted.

Edit: Some of the comments above offer different solutions.

In place of `Math.abs()`, one could always run a simple check of `if ( result < 0 )` and then multiply the result by -1 if true. I'm not sure how much this would impact speed, but I don't think it would be by much.

The most sophisticated answer yet has you run a bitwise AND on the result with 0x7FFFFFFF in order to trim the negative bit. This has no impact on speed, and does indeed ensure a positive value.